# Avoid app trying to call the Fragment's empty constructor when the app has been killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Is there a way, when an activity starts, for recognizing if the app had been killed (e.g. because of low memory) and then avoiding the app to try to load its previous fragments with their empty constructors?

I need to have Fragments with non-empty constructors and their parameters are not serializable (I ca not save them when the app goes on background). If the app is killed I want to recreate it by myself, creating again all fragments as if the app started for the first time.

Is it possible?

Comment: "I need to have Fragments with non-empty constructors" -- why? Use setters for data that cannot be put into the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`, pushing the data from the activity into the fragment in the activity's `onCreate()`. Or, pull the data from the hosting activity in `onAttach()` or `onActivityCreated()` of the fragment.

Comment: Great! That is the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any way to prevent an activity from recreating its fragments. That's not to say that there is no such mechanism, but if there is one, it is not commonly used.

But a constructor is just one way of getting data into an object. If you support a zero-argument public constructor, so Android can recreate your fragments, you can:

- Use setters for data that cannot be put into the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`, pushing the data from the activity into the fragment in the activity's onCreate(), or
- Pull the data from the hosting activity in `onAttach()` or `onActivityCreated()` of the fragment, or
- Use special hooks for this in your event bus implementation, such as producers in Otto or sticky events in greenrobot's EventBus, or
- Have the fragment recreate the data itself (e.g., open up a fresh socket connection to the server, to replace the socket that was gone when the process was terminated)

There are probably other patterns as well, but those should help give you some ideas for supporting zero-argument public constructors.